# php - warning when inserting JPEG into SQL Database

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to upload an image into an SQL server using a simple form however I'm being faced with the following warning, which also prevents me from uploading the image:

> Warning: odbc_exec(): in C:\wamp\www\inputform\index2.php on line 10

**Line 10**: `$sql_run = odbc_exec($con, $sql);`

The code is:

```
<?php

require ('connect.inc.php');

    if(ISSET($_POST['submit'])){
            $imagename = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
            $imagedata = file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
            echo $imagename." ".$imagedata;
            $sql = "INSERT INTO test.dbo.images (imageid, imagedata)  VALUES('','$imagedata')";
            $sql_run = odbc_exec($con, $sql);
                echo "Query with the following details has been executed: <br>".$imagename;


    }
    else{
        echo 'Is not set';
    }
?>
<form action="index2.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Image: <input type="file" name="image"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

The file connect.inc.php consists of the code below:

```
<?php
$serverName="TESTSERV\SQLEXPRESS";
$dsn='odbc-test';
$user = 'user';
$password = 'password';
$db = 'test';
if(!$con = odbc_connect($dsn, $user, $password)){
    echo "Not Connected";
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance.
J

Comment: Your title is misleading (in contrast with your description). I'm not sure its about retrieving anything from the database....

Comment: @PlatinumIndustries: Thanks for that. My mistake. Fixed it now. Back to the question please :)

Comment: can you post the datatypes of  `imageid`, and `imagedata` from the database, wheather string or intager or varchar.

Comment: **image** id: varchar and **imagedata**: varbinary(8000)

Answer (score 0):

The query looks fine so the only logical explanation is that the datatypes you are trying to insert are not same. Make sure that `imageid` and `imagedata` datatypes are `varchar`

EDIT: Make sure that the datatypes are same. here is the updated answer.

```
<?php

require ('connect.inc.php');

if(ISSET($_POST['submit'])){
        $imagename = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
        $imagedata = (binary)file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
        echo $imagename." ".$imagedata;
        $sql = "INSERT INTO test.dbo.images (imageid, imagedata)  VALUES('','.$imagedata.')";
        $sql_run = odbc_exec($con, $sql);
            echo "Query with the following details has been executed: <br>".$imagename;


}
else{
    echo 'Is not set';
}
```

?>

note: `$imagedata = (binary)file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);`

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Platinum Industries. Unfortunately I was still prompted with the same warning message. The image types are **image** id: varchar and **imagedata**: varbinary(8000)

Comment: `imagedata` is the culprit. try casting it to binary before inserting. i.e `$imagedata = (binary)file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);`, i've edited my answer.

Comment: Still with the error. I can't see anything wrong with the syntax. Can't understand what the problem is.

Comment: You are trying to insert **imagedata** with a datatype of 'string' instead of `varbinary` as you have set in your database, convert it to binary first before using it in `odbc_exec()`

Comment: Im inserting the binary generated generated with this: `$imagedata = (binary)file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);`  .|
If I echo image data, I get a bunch of characters which is generally the image's actual data.

Comment: can you try to echo this and tell me what it gives `echo gettype($imagedata)`

Comment: The answer to that is string.  How do I change that to the actual data type of the database field please (varbinary) ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80871/discussion-between-platinum-industries-and-joebegborg07).